# Atomic Vector Error with Shiny CSV Upload for Dygraph Output

Tags: r, shiny, dygraphs

I am asking users to upload a CSV file which will then give them the chance to select a "Channel" that is based on one of the headers of the CSV file.  When they select a file to chart, it will appear in a `Dygraph` output.

I am running into an issue where I am receiving an error:

`Error in uploadedFile1$Time : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can fix this in my script?

The data for this example is here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzg7bDcyZobbc1Zoc0VoN3ZzSmM/view?usp=sharing

Here is my ui.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  navbarPage("Data Webpage",
             tabPanel("Data Selection",
tabPanel("Upload a CSV File:",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
                                    accept=c('text/csv', 
                                             'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                                             '.csv')),
                          selectInput("uploadChannels1", label = "Choose a Channel",
                                      choices = NULL),
                          fileInput('file2', 'Choose CSV File',
                                    accept=c('text/csv', 
                                             'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                                             '.csv')),
                          selectInput("uploadChannels2", label = "Choose a Channel",
                                      choices = NULL),
                          tags$hr(),
                          checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
                          radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
                                       c(Comma=',',
                                         Semicolon=';',
                                         Tab='\t'),
                                       ',')

                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                              dygraphOutput('graph')
                        ))



                        )

                               )))
```

Here is my Server.R

```
library(xts)
library(shiny)
library(dygraphs)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
observeEvent(uploadedFile1, {
    updateSelectizeInput(session, 'uploadChannels1', choices = names(uploadedFile1))
  })
  observeEvent(uploadedFile2, {
    updateSelectizeInput(session, 'uploadChannels2', choices = names(uploadedFile2))
  })

  # Upload the CSV File 
  uploadedFile1 <- reactive({
    validate(need(input$file1, FALSE)) # This is like a better "if (is.null(input$file1)) return(NULL)"
    uf1 <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath)
    uf1 <- strftime(strptime(uf1$Time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), "%H:%M:%S")
  })

  uploadedFile2 <- reactive({
    validate(need(input$file2, FALSE)) # This is like a better "if (is.null(input$file2)) return(NULL)"
    uf2 <- read.csv(input$file2$datapath)
    uf2 <- strftime(strptime(uf2$Time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), "%H:%M:%S")

  })

  observeEvent(uploadedFile1(), {
    updateSelectizeInput(session, 'uploadChannels1', choices = names(uploadedFile1()))
  })
  observeEvent(uploadedFile2(), {
    updateSelectizeInput(session, 'uploadChannels2', choices = names(uploadedFile2()))
  })

  output$graph <- renderDygraph({


    # Clean up the loaded CSV File, convert Time column to a Time Object for Dygraph.
    uploadedFile1 <- uploadedFile1()
    uploadedFile2 <- uploadedFile2()
    uploadedFile1$Time <- as.POSIXct(strptime(uploadedFile1$Time,"%H:%M:%S"))
    uploadedFile2$Time <- as.POSIXct(strptime(uploadedFile2$Time,"%H:%M:%S"))

    uploadedFile1$ctime <- strptime(paste(uploadedFile1$Time), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    uploadedFile2$ctime <- strptime(paste(uploadedFile2$Time), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

    # Update the SelectInput and store the value in component5 to be used in the graph.
    selectedInput1 <- input$uploadChannels1
    selectedInput2 <- input$uploadChannels2
    component5 <- uploadedFile1[, selectedInput1]
    component6 <- uploadedFile2[, selectedInput2]
    cbinded <- cbind(component5, component6)

        xts(cbinded, uploadedFile1$Time, uploadedFile2$Time)  %>% 
      dygraph()

    })

})
```

Comment: have you tried to test (outside shiny) your dataset and with    xts(cbinded, uploadedFile1$Time, uploadedFile2$Time)  %>% 
      dygraph()?...basically just try to isolate your problem

Comment: So I saved my file in `test`.  When I try to run `test[["Time"]]` it tells me that the subscript is out of bounds.  When I try to run `test$Time`, it tells me that the $ operator is not valid for atomic vector.  This is after doing `strftime(strptime(test$Time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), "%H:%M:%S")`

Comment: can you run str(test) in R?

Comment: `test <- read.csv("Test_file1.csv", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=TRUE)`
`test <- strftime(strptime(test$Time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), "%H:%M:%S")`
`str(test)`
 chr [1:2185] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
>

Comment: from the str() output it looks like you have only one variable so you're doing something wrong

Comment: Yeah, this line: `test <- strftime(strptime(test$Time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), "%H:%M:%S")` is causing the change from the matrix to the atomic vector.

Comment: Do you know how I could possibly solve the problem of it changing the time column to an atomic vector?

Comment: I had some difficulty reading your csv file because of the header; and in your strftime(strptime(uf1$Time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), "%H:%M:%S") expression but why are you using %Y-%m-%d when I only time, jour and seconds in you file?

Comment: Regardless of whether I have %Y-%m-%d in or not, it's still changing the time column to an atomic vector, which I am unable to subset later using the $ operator.

Comment: actually that's the problem, you are selecting the wrong format so it can't work.  try strftime(strptime("2015-01-01 05:35:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), "%H:%M:%S") and this strftime(strptime("05:35:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), "%H:%M:%S") which would explain your str(test) chr [1:2185] NA NA NA...

Comment: Are you suggesting that I use `strftime(strptime("2015-01-01 05:35:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), "%H:%M:%S")` and `strftime(strptime("05:35:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), "%H:%M:%S")`together?  Thanks for your support :)

Comment: no I am just trying to show you the difference. so in your code, you should try uf2 <- strftime(strptime(uf2$Time, "%H:%M:%S"), "%H:%M:%S"); but like I said earlier I had trouble reading your dataset. so make sure when you run your code it reads your dataset correctly

Comment: Hmm, I'm still having issues.  I am trying now to play around with how the CSV is read and how the columns are classified.

Comment: I was able to fix those issues by changing the header

Comment: What did you change the header to?

Comment: for the sake of the exercise, I just replaced by V1 to V5

Comment: Ugh sorry, I'm not following.  What was the line of code you used?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100704/discussion-between-mlavoie-and-nick).